# jquery-ui-dialog: why does clicking on elements inside dialog spawn more dialogs?

Tags: jquery

```
$(top.document).ready(function () {   

   $(document).click(processAction);



function processAction(e){
    var clicked = e.target;
newDialog("You've Clicked On A Link !")

function newDialog(mytitle){
   var $dialog = $('<div id="myunique"></div>')
        .html("<a href='http://sss.com'>click</a>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: mytitle
        });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false
}

});
```

The problem I am having is that when I click anywhere in the dialog, a new dialog popups, and it seems to produce several of these in a row.

My goal is:
catch all the clicks on page EXCEPT the elements inside the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is probably here:

```
$(document).click(processAction);
```

this means that any time you click anywhere on your page, the `processAction()` method runs!

change this so that it only runs when a button or link is clicked and it should solve your problem.

EDIT: according to your edit you want to capture clicks outside your dialog box. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: i tried $('body').delegate('*:not(#mymenu *)','click', processAction); and it doesn't work

Comment: yes, because that means that whenever someone clicks anywhere on the page it will run your method. set your click handler to something like `$('.mylink').click(processAction)`

Comment: even doing this $('body').delegate('a:not(#mymenu *)','click', processAction); results in a new dialog spawning when I click the link inside the dialog....

Comment: the reason I am doing this is, I need to catch all the clicks EXCEPT the elements inside the dialog.

Comment: tried the event.stopPropagation method but as soon as I click on teh link, the dialog appears and then it navigates to the following page.